# Pythonでsafariをプライベートモードで開きたい

Tags: python, python3, selenium

pythonでブラウザを開いて、WEBサイトを表示する通常の方法は

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> url = "https://www.google.com"
>>> webbrowser.open(url)
```

となると思いますが、これを
safariで、かつ**ブライベートモード**で開きたいのですが、可能でしょうか？

Comment: [seleniumのWebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/ja/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/)でChromeなら、プライベートモードを指定するオプション`--incognito`があるようです。[Python/Selenium incognito/private mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27630190/9014308), [Selenium Chrome Webdriver in Incognito Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71617458/9014308) Safariには無いようです [Robotframework - Open Safari in Private mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72965213/9014308) が、古い情報ですが実は常にプライベートモードでは？ [How do I launch Safari Web driver using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45289886/9014308) という記事があるようです。

Comment: 上記より少し新しい(それでも3年前)常にプライベートモードと同様に動作するという記事。[Launching Safari in private mode using WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57294932/9014308)